# How to fix "Call to a member function offset() on array" erron in my yii2 project

Tags: php, yii, pagination, yii2

I want to set pagination in my Blogs page.  Before pagination this action work.

```
    $data = [];
    $query = Blog::find()->where(['status'=>1])->multilingual()->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])->all();


   $count = count($query);


    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count]);

    // limit the query using the pagination and retrieve the articles
    $data['blog'] = $query->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit)->all();


    return $this->render('blog-list',['data'=>$data, 'pagination'=>$pagination]);
```

Whenever I set PageSize, problem didn't solve yet.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `all()`

```
$query = Blog::find()->where(['status'=>1])->multilingual()->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC]);

$totalCount = clone $query;
$pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => count($totalCount->all())]);
```

Comment: It's a bad way for performance. 1. The code has two copy Query object 2. `count($totalCount->all())` - gets ALL records from database it makes excess workload to database

Comment: @MaximFedorov You can write separate query that gives you total no. of records no need for `all()` there. For first case try to run your example and check total count. Use at least 50 records for better result.

Comment: 1. ActiveDataProvider that is used GridView doesn't select all row from table to calculate count records. It use `->count()` function. You can see it in git repository https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/ActiveDataProvider.php#L169

Comment: 2. ActiveDataProvide clones a query, but why? If you look at the detail in git repository you can see ActiveDataProvider clones a query before its modification. And this fact has a point because query object is passed by reference and any modifications of a user query will be a bad practice that can make some problems.

Comment: @MaximFedorov That's what i explained about totalCount. IMO, Use separate query for totalCount ,This answer is according to OP's question not about performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because `$query` variable contains an array of records instead of the query object. If you want to modified query you can keep it.

```
$query = Blog::find()->where(['status'=>1])->multilingual();

$count = $query->count();
$pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count]);

// limit the query using the pagination and retrieve the articles
$data['blog'] = $query->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit)->all();


return $this->render('blog-list',['data'=>$data, 'pagination'=>$pagination]);
```